# Parse lines from two column files

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need tiny help.

I want parse in bash  from following two files lines (just from second file) where  second columns are identical but theit first columns are unique:

```
file1 
111403787651,111915870316631
111408649892,111917070744403
111408653841,111919750018614
111408655467,111917420005028

file2
111403787651,111915870316631
444444444441,111917070744403
222222222222,333333333333333
```

**Output : 
just from second file**

```
444444444441,111917070744403
```

thanks

Comment: Could the data in file 1 have entries of the form `111,222` and `112,222` (same second column value, different column 1 values)?

Comment: "Second columns are identical" means what, exactly? "Where the second column has been found in the first file"? Similarly, does "first column unique" mean "first column *not* found in the first file"?

Comment: ...do the pairings between first and second columns in the first file have any effect at all, or could the order of each column be entirely randomized without changing the output?

Comment: Can this be solved with `grep`, `cut` and `|`? No cheating with temp files!

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1; next} $2 in a && $1 != a[$2]' file1 file2
444444444441,111917070744403
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I've correctly read your intent (a big assumption, as the language in the question is largely imprecise), the following is a native-bash implementation require no external tools, and emits the desired output given the inputs in the question:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^ - NOT /bin/sh, as this requires bash-only (indeed, bash-4.x+-only) features

# read first file's contents 
declare -A first=( ) second=( ) # define associative arrays; requires bash 4.0
while IFS=, read -r a b; do     # read columns into variables a and b
  first[$a]=1; second[$b]=1     # set associative-array keys for each
done <file1                     # ...doing the above reading from file1

# iterate through second file's contents
while IFS=, read -r a b; do     # again, read into a and b
  if [[ ${second[$b]} && ! ${first[$a]} ]]; then # if we already saw b, and did not see a
    printf '%s,%s\n' "$a" "$b"                   # ...then emit output.
  fi
done <file2                     # ...doing the above reading from file2
```

---

References:

- [BashFAQ #001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) ("How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (or field-by-field)?")
- [BashFAQ #006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Associative_Arrays) ("How can I use [...] associative arrays?")

Comment: Interesting functional difference between this and @karakfa's awk answer is where w,x and y,z appear in file1 and w,z in file2. The awk script will output w,z while the bash script won't since the awk script requires the first field to be associated with the 2nd field value in file1 while the bash script just requires the first field to be present for any 2nd field value in file1. Too bad the OP didn't include that case in their sample input/output so we'd know what they want. I'm always surprised by how little thought goes into the examples.... :-(.